# why does the outline of sections of the body glow like this?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, vertices

[image]

i want to know why this model vertices are glowing like this and how to stop this glow? this is getting annoying and i dont know how to fix it.

the blend file is here: [image]

Comment: @Chris Edge crease is pink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the *Mark Sharp*, it allows you to keep the edges sharp if you've shaded smooth your object, you can remove with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Clear Sharp*.

To add to John's answer, if you want to keep them but make them invisible, in Blender 4 the display option is not available in the *Viewport Overlays* anymore, it's in the *Mesh Edit Mode Overlays*:

[image]

Comment: Yes. I missed that one because I opened the file in Blender 3.6.8.

Answer (score 3):

As @moonboots says it's because the edges/vertices have been Marked Sharp. You can toggle their visibility on the <kbd>Show Overlays</kbd> menu by clicking on <kbd>Sharp</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Oh yes I missed the option in Blender 4 because it's a new panel (Mesh Edit Mode Overlays)

Comment: @moonboots I wouldn't call it a "new panel", Blender 2.83 is quite old nowadays... (or that's the oldest version I got left on my PC, I think it's been there before)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the panel I'm talking about seems to be here since Blender 4, it's not the Viewport Overlays anymore, see my edit @Gordon Brinkmann

Comment: @moonboots Oops, you're right... it has been moved. But the option to disable visibility has been there before, so no need to use _Clear Sharp_, because maybe the edges need to be sharp for some reason.

Comment: Sure, I just meant that I couldn't find it first when I checked the Viewport Overlays